# RegisterWaitForSingleObject Windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I am using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to wait on a serial comm events as registered with `WaitCommEvent`.

The code works well on Windows XP however always throws an exception somewhere in the treadpool when running on Windows 7.

The stack trace shows

```
ntdll.dll!_TppWaiterpThread@4()  + 0x3a7ee bytes    
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Is there any way to get this function to operate correctly in Windows 7 or will I need to re-write with support for the new [Windows Vista/7 threadpool functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is an example of how I am calling the code. As stated this works flawlessly on XP

```
// Calback is on an object defined as a static function
class CommPortCallback
{
public:
    static void WINAPI serialLayerCallback( PVOID lpParameter, 
                                  BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired )
    {
        ....
    }
};

// wait is registered later as such
RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&pWaitData->callbackHandle, m_readOverlapped, 
        CommPortCallback::serialLayerCallback, pBaseCallback, 
        INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE)
```

Comment: Using a threadpool, and then having to synchronize between threads, seems like serious overkill for a serial port.  Why not just add the event handle to your main event loop (`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`)?

Comment: My program needs to scale to hundreds of active com port connections this is why I am using a threadpool

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, print the thread ID every time your callback is invoked, before accessing any parameters.  When the crash happens, compare the thread ID to the most recently invoked callback.  Also, is there any data accessed by multiple callbacks?  Race conditions can manifest differently on different hardware or different versions of the OS.

Comment: How did this compile?  You're passing an OVERLAPPED instead of a HANDLE.

Comment: @Hans: I think that's possible, when `STRICT` is not set, and `HANDLE` is just a `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the code calling `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.

At a guess, your callback function has the wrong calling convention or wrong parameter types, you're using a function pointer cast to overrule the compiler's complaint, and then the stack pointer is left misaligned after the call.

---

With the code the cause is now clear: You're passing in a pointer to the `OVERLAPPED` structure, instead of the event handle.  It doesn't seem like this should ever have worked correctly on XP, but whether or not it crashes or fails silently could well vary with Windows version.

Comment: Added code to question. However the calling convention is unlikely to be incorrect as it works on XP

Comment: @JProgrammer: This may or may not make a difference, but you're supposed to use the `CALLBACK` macro when declaring the callback function, not `WINAPI`.  See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687066.aspx).

Comment: @JProgrammer: Also, "works on XP" isn't any proof of correctness.  It just means that XP was more tolerant of whatever error is in your code.

Comment: I was actually passing in the overlapped to `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` which ended up being the problem, q updated.
If someone puts in this answer I'll accept it.